# How to conditionally replace values in a pandas dataframe column with values from another column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I know this type of question has been asked many times before. With the answers provided I am not able to move beyond this point.

I have a dataframe named areas. I want have a new column which takes the values from column area1 unless the value is NaN then the value must be taken from area2.

```
area1 area2
NaN   100
NaN   101
NaN   102
A     103
B     104
C     105
```

I have tried a bunch of things but am stuck. The last thing I tried was.

```
areas['area3'] = np.where(areas['area1'].isnan, areas['areas2'])
```

Help would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missing the 2nd condition and function name should be `isna`

```
areas['area3'] = np.where(areas['area1'].isna(), areas['area2'], areas['area1'])
```